# Update a file only if it exists Node

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to update a file using NodeJs only if the file exists.
How to do that.
I read the node docs and fs.exists is deprecated.
If I use fs.writeFile directly it will create a new file if one doesn't exist.

How to update a file only if it exists.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use fs.open and fs.write.

fs.open flags you need:

```
  * 'r+' - Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.
```

Comment: That was gonna be my answer as well =D

Comment: You can do that with `fs.writeFile()` as well. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Used 'r+' flag with fs.writeFile. Thanks

Comment: @MadaraUchiha on writing fs.writeFile with r+, it doesn't overwrite the file. It just replaces the characters. How to overwrite the file?

Answer (score 1):

From [NodeJs 4.x documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback)

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.access('/path/to/your/file', fs.F_OK, (err) => {
   if (!err) {
     // File exists, update your file
   }
});
```

`fs.F_OK` - File is visible to the calling process. This is useful for determining if a file exists, but says nothing about rwx permissions. Default if no mode is specified.

You can also use the flags `fs.R_OK | fs.W_OK | fs.X_OK` to additionally check the **rwx** permissions of the calling process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myFile = './mono.txt';

try {
  if (!fs.accessSync(myFile)) console.log('File does already exist');
}
catch (exc) {
  fs.writeFile(myFile);
}
```

Comment: fs.existsSync(path) is deprecated.

Comment: Try `fs.accessSync(...)`

Comment: No sync IO please.